# Find number of rows in a line - Python openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, row, line, openpyxl

My workbook has differing number of columns for each row. I want to find an integer in a long string. My code works if the number of columns is always the same. Unfortunatelly when the number of colums differ there is an error because some of the cells are empty. (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find')

How can I figure out the number of colums for every single line to avoid this error? Any other method to invent that problem is very much appreciated.

```
num_rows = List.max_row
num_cols = List.max_column
while i < (num_rows + 1):
    filename = List.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    worksheet_AS.cell(row=i, column=1, value=filename)
    while k < (num_cols+1):
        stringresult = List.cell(row=i, column=k).value
        start = stringresult.find("AS:i:")
        worksheet_AS.cell(row=i,column=k,value=int(stringresult[start+5:start+8]))
        k = k + 1
    k = 2
    i=i+1
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why are you incrementing `k` by one, then immediately setting it to 2?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That was a formatting error. k=2, is then incremented and set back to 2 after the while loop

Comment: Just add a conditional `if stringresult is not None` to you code. Also, your code could make better use of the openpyxl API and more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with an if question:

```
while k < (num_cols+1):
        stringresult=List.cell(row=i, column=k).value

        if type(stringresult) is str:
            start=stringresult.find("PI:i:")
            end=stringresult.find("PI:f:")
            worksheet_PI.cell(row=i,column=k,value=int(stringresult[start+5:end]))

        k=k+1

    k=2
```